# What provokes the android gallery to find images?

Tags: android, gallery

I have an app that takes photos and puts them on the sdcard. After some time they appear in the Android photo gallery.  I'm unclear what that time interval is and am curious if there's some way I can provoke whatever Android does to scan the drive so that the images show up faster? Or is there a folder I should be saving them in to accelerate this recognition? Or is there nothing I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is handled by the Android `MediaScanner`.  This is what scans the phone for new media and stores it in the Android media database.  I believe the time frame which it runs is device specific.  However, you can call it manually:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(destFileOrFolder);
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
    sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
```